# Access text inputs in dynamic HTML table

Tags: html, forms, google-apps-script, html-table

I am trying to follow a guide to  [Dynamically Add/Delete HTML Table Rows Using Javascript](https://www.etutorialspoint.com/index.php/11-dynamically-add-delete-html-table-rows-using-javascript). I have ported the code to my needs, but I am confused as to how to get my data out of the nested html within the table. Ideally, I want to export it as an array to Google Script.

My test involves filling in a row for the form, then submitting (running function sendIT), but when I have tried to check (with alert) each individual cell value, I get this:

```
<input type="text" name="tag[]" value=""> //i.e. no value?!
```

I was expecting to find inputted values there and start building arrays for each column.

How can I access the input values?

Many thanks in advance.

HTML code + Google Script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function addRows(){ 
    var table = document.getElementById('emptbl');
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    var cellCount = table.rows[0].cells.length; 
    var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
    for(var i =0; i <= cellCount; i++){
        var cell = 'cell'+i;
        cell = row.insertCell(i);
        var copycel = document.getElementById('col'+i).innerHTML;
        cell.innerHTML=copycel;
    
    }
}
function deleteRows(){
    var table = document.getElementById('emptbl');
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    if(rowCount > '2'){
        var row = table.deleteRow(rowCount-1);
        rowCount--;
    }
    else{
        alert('There should be atleast one row');
    }
}
function sendIt(){
    var oTable = document.getElementById('emptbl');

    //gets rows of table
    var rowLength = oTable.rows.length;

    //loops through rows    
    for (i = 0; i < rowLength; i++){

      //gets cells of current row  
       var oCells = oTable.rows.item(i).cells;

       //gets amount of cells of current row
       var cellLength = oCells.length;

       //loops through each cell in current row
       for(var j = 0; j < cellLength; j++){

              // get your cell info here

              var cellVal = oCells.item(j).innerHTML;
              alert(cellVal);
              alert(cellVal.value)
           }
    }
  //alert("hello from sendit");
  google.script.run.appendRowFromTableSubmit(document.getElementById('emptbl'));
  alert("hello2");

}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="#" method="post">    
    <table id="emptbl">
        <tr>
      <th>Tag</th>
            <th>Size</th>
            <th>Notes</th>
            <th>Species</th> 
            <th>Gender</th> 
        </tr> 
        <tr>
      <td id="col0"><input type="text" name="tag[]" value="" /></td> 
            <td id="col1"><input type="text" name="size[]" value="" /></td> 
            <td id="col2"><input type="text" name="notes[]" value="" /></td> 
            <td id="col3"> 
            <select name="species[]" id="species"> 
            <option value="0">Select Species</option> 
            <option value="1">Lobster</option>
            <option value="2">Brown</option>
            <option value="3">Velvet</option>
            </select> 
                </td> 
      <td id="col4"> <input type="text" name="gender[]" value="" /></td> 
        </tr>  
    </table> 
    <table> 
        <tr> 
            <td><input type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="addRows()" /></td> 
            <td><input type="button" value="Delete Row" onclick="deleteRows()" /></td> 
            <td><input type="submit" value="Submit1" onclick="sendIt()" /></td> 
        </tr>  
    </table> 
 </form> 
</body> 

    <div >
      
      <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="submitForm();">
  </form>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div id="thanks" style="display: none;">
    <p>Thank you for sumbitting! The specimen data has now been populated, please fill in the specifics.</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because I couldn't use PHP in google script, I ended up finding another dynamic row code example ([source](http://talkerscode.com/webtricks/add-edit-and-delete-rows-from-table-dynamically-using-javascript.php)) and was able to make a get work simply

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      function sendIt() {
        get_row(1);
      }
      function edit_row(no) {
        document.getElementById("edit_button" + no).style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("save_button" + no).style.display = "block";

        var name = document.getElementById("name_row" + no);
        var country = document.getElementById("country_row" + no);
        var age = document.getElementById("age_row" + no);

        var name_data = name.innerHTML;
        var country_data = country.innerHTML;
        var age_data = age.innerHTML;

        name.innerHTML =
          "<input type='text' id='name_text" +
          no +
          "' value='" +
          name_data +
          "'>";
        country.innerHTML =
          "<input type='text' id='country_text" +
          no +
          "' value='" +
          country_data +
          "'>";
        age.innerHTML =
          "<input type='text' id='age_text" +
          no +
          "' value='" +
          age_data +
          "'>";
      }

      function save_row(no) {
        var name_val = document.getElementById("name_text" + no).value;
        var country_val = document.getElementById("country_text" + no).value;
        var age_val = document.getElementById("age_text" + no).value;

        document.getElementById("name_row" + no).innerHTML = name_val;
        document.getElementById("country_row" + no).innerHTML = country_val;
        document.getElementById("age_row" + no).innerHTML = age_val;

        document.getElementById("edit_button" + no).style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("save_button" + no).style.display = "none";
      }

      function delete_row(no) {
        document.getElementById("row" + no + "").outerHTML = "";
      }

      function add_row() {
        var new_name = document.getElementById("new_name").value;
        var new_country = document.getElementById("new_country").value;
        var new_age = document.getElementById("new_age").value;

        var table = document.getElementById("data_table");
        var table_len = table.rows.length - 1;
        var row = (table.insertRow(table_len).outerHTML =
          "<tr id='row" +
          table_len +
          "'><td id='name_row" +
          table_len +
          "'>" +
          new_name +
          "</td><td id='country_row" +
          table_len +
          "'>" +
          new_country +
          "</td><td id='age_row" +
          table_len +
          "'>" +
          new_age +
          "</td><td><input type='button' id='edit_button" +
          table_len +
          "' value='Edit' class='edit' onclick='edit_row(" +
          table_len +
          ")'> <input type='button' id='save_button" +
          table_len +
          "' value='Save' class='save' onclick='save_row(" +
          table_len +
          ")'> <input type='button' value='Delete' class='delete' onclick='delete_row(" +
          table_len +
          ")'></td></tr>");

        document.getElementById("new_name").value = "";
        document.getElementById("new_country").value = "";
        document.getElementById("new_age").value = "";
      }

      function get_row(no) {
        alert(document.getElementById("name_row" + no).innerHTML);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="wrapper">
      <table
        align="center"
        cellspacing="2"
        cellpadding="5"
        id="data_table"
        border="1"
      >
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Country</th>
          <th>Age</th>
        </tr>

        <tr id="row1">
          <td id="name_row1">Ankit</td>
          <td id="country_row1">India</td>
          <td id="age_row1">20</td>
          <td>
            <input
              type="button"
              id="edit_button1"
              value="Edit"
              class="edit"
              onclick="edit_row('1')"
            />
            <input
              type="button"
              id="save_button1"
              value="Save"
              class="save"
              onclick="save_row('1')"
            />
            <input
              type="button"
              value="Delete"
              class="delete"
              onclick="delete_row('1')"
            />
          </td>
        </tr>

        <tr id="row2">
          <td id="name_row2">Shawn</td>
          <td id="country_row2">Canada</td>
          <td id="age_row2">26</td>
          <td>
            <input
              type="button"
              id="edit_button2"
              value="Edit"
              class="edit"
              onclick="edit_row('2')"
            />
            <input
              type="button"
              id="save_button2"
              value="Save"
              class="save"
              onclick="save_row('2')"
            />
            <input
              type="button"
              value="Delete"
              class="delete"
              onclick="delete_row('2')"
            />
          </td>
        </tr>

        <tr id="row3">
          <td id="name_row3">Rahul</td>
          <td id="country_row3">India</td>
          <td id="age_row3">19</td>
          <td>
            <input
              type="button"
              id="edit_button3"
              value="Edit"
              class="edit"
              onclick="edit_row('3')"
            />
            <input
              type="button"
              id="save_button3"
              value="Save"
              class="save"
              onclick="save_row('3')"
            />
            <input
              type="button"
              value="Delete"
              class="delete"
              onclick="delete_row('3')"
            />
          </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td><input type="text" id="new_name" /></td>
          <td><input type="text" id="new_country" /></td>
          <td><input type="text" id="new_age" /></td>
          <td>
            <input
              type="button"
              class="add"
              onclick="add_row();"
              value="Add Row"
            />
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <input type="submit" onclick="sendIt();" value="submit" />
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

You can also include a html parsing library to help. Then access the item of each row using a for each loop similar to yours.

```
       include('simple_html_dom.php');

       $html = str_get_html($string); // Parse the HTML, stored as a 
       //string in $string
       $rows = $html->find('tr'); // Find all rows in the table

       //Loop through each row
       foreach ($rows as $row) {
       //Loop through each child (cell) of the row
       foreach ($row->children() as $cell) {
       echo $cell->plaintext; // Display the contents of each                                  
       //cell - this is the value you want to extract
       }
       }
```

Good luck!

You should rework your form and give it an attribute called onSubmit. The only way to dynamically access your input is by submitting it. Otherwise the page has no means of knowing what was submitted and the values aren't processed. Any reference to the value will be null as it was when the page loaded.

```
 <form method="post" action onsubmit=myFunction('document.getelementbyid('param1')> 
    <fieldset>
    <label for="label 1">Label1</label>   
    <input type="text" name="someName" value="" id= "param1" />
    </fieldset>
    <input type ="submit" value="clickMe" name="submit"/>
    </form>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the solution. Unfortunately, that doesn't work in Google Script, as PHP is not supported. I ended up finding a solution using another dynamic row solution (see below solution). Perhaps innerHTML is the key method?

Comment: Nice solution :D Good job. Is it meant as a project for yourself? Homework? Environment?

Comment: I am working as a part of a survey assessing the impact of a managed Marine protected area :) https://doi.org/10.3389/fmars.2020.00076 more here if you are interested.